# Font getting reset in virtual console on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, fonts, console

I have set a custom font on my virtual console (vt1) using the following command:

```
shell> setfont ter-114f
```

If I switch to X (using Ctrl+Alt+F7) and come back to the virtual console (using Ctrl+Alt+F1), the display isn't proper.  Looks like the screen size is getting reset (previously set to 28 rows before switching).

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your distribution.

#### Arch Linux

In Arch Linux, once you have selected the font from `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/` that you would like to set, you need to add it to your `/etc/rc.conf` like so:

```
CONSOLEFONT="lat2-16"
```

and then add the consolefont hook to your `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect pata scsi sata filesystems consolefont"
```

and regenerate the image:

```
# mkinitcpio -p kernel26
```

#### Ubuntu/Debian

In Ubuntu/Debian, select your font from `/usr/share/consolefonts/` and then edit `/etc/default/console-setup` and add an entry like:

```
CODESET="Lat15"
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="16"
```

and to make it permanent:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

#### Fedora

The available fonts are listed in `/lib/kbd/consolefonts/`.

Specify the desired font in `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` file by modifying the SYSCONF entry.

```
SYSFONT="lat2-16"
```

#### References

1. Arch: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Console_fonts
2. Fedora: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/09/30/change-console-font-in-fedora

Answer (score 1):

Often the X server will save the old video state when it starts, and restore that when switching back to the text console.  If you change the text console video state in between, it will get clobbered.  Maybe KMS (kernel mode setting) will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to copy your font in ~/.fonts or /usr/share/fonts. Carefully, /usr/share/fonts has some dir, please read them.
Then for ~/.fonst run :

```
fc-cache -v -f #with your username
```

And for /usr/share/fonts run :

```
fc-cache -v -f #with superuser
```